# How to assign functions with variable number of parameters to single variable?

Tags: kotlin

Experimenting with Kotlin, I wish to assign functions/lambdas to a variable.

These functions/lambdas all have a *variable* (zero or more) number of parameters, and they all return nothing (a `Unit`).

Here are examples of some valid functions/lambdas:

```
a: Int -> Unit
a: String, b: Int -> Unit
() -> Unit
```

(e.g. zero or more parameters returning a `Unit`)

How can I declare such a variable?

I tried with:

```
var test: KCallable<Unit> = { var a = 1 } // COMPILE ERROR
```

but it seems `() -> Unit` is not compatible with `KCallable<Unit>`, so I assume I'm using the wrong interface. What is the correct one? (except for `Any`)

Comment: How would you _use_ such a variable?

Comment: @LouisWasserman type testing, then invoking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Function<Unit>` as such a base type. See the [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html) for more information.